# jquery autocomplete to show 2 values separated by semicolon

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, autocomplete

i have a text field where autocomplete suggestions for name and address should appear separated by a semicolon(;).
I am using codeigniter and following is the jquery code:

```
//to retrieve the name and address values
var business=new Object();
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': base_url + '/controller_name/method1',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            bb = value.b_name+'; '+value.b_add;
            if(key==0)
                bb_json = JSON.stringify(bb);
            else
                bb_json += JSON.stringify(bb);
        });     
    }
});
```

above code is working fine and saves all names and addresses in bb_json. Now i want it to appear in autocomplete suggestion list. The code i have written for this is as follows-

```
$('#b_name').autocomplete({
    source      : bb_json,
    max         : 5,
    minLength   : 2,
    open        : function(event, ui) {
        $('ul.ui-autocomplete').addClass('f-dropdown').attr('id', 'bb_ul');
        $(this).autocomplete("widget");  
    }
});
```

But this is not working. Can someone help, please???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must generate a valid javascript array in your $ajax().success() callback:

```
$.ajax({
    'async': false,
    'global': false,
    'url': base_url + '/controller_name/method1',
    'dataType': "json",
    'success': function (data) {
        //data = [{b_name:"foo1",b_add:"bar1"},{b_name:"foo2",b_add:"bar2"},{b_name:"foo3",b_add:"bar3"}]
        bb_json = []

        $.each(data, function(key, value){
            bb = value.b_name+'; '+value.b_add;
            bb_json.push(bb);
        });
    }
});
```

This work.

Answer (score 0):

change open with the following code:

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
...
}
```

also remove the autocompleter inside the open function

may be this will help you [Autocompleter](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data)